# Linq бинарный файл

Tags: c#, linq

Провожу сериализацию в бинарник, потом эти записанные данные могут обновится и нужно сделать запись об этом в бинарник. Как можно найти нужную запись и обновить?   Через linq получится? Или лучше для таких целей использовать сериализацию  в xml?

Спасибо!

Comment: Вы хотите избежать процедуры: Десериализация бинарника в коллекцию -> Поиск по коллекции нужного элемента -> Изменение элемента ->Сериализация в бинарный файл обратно. Так?

Comment: @Bulson конечно, тогда мне, в моем случае, проще просто перезаписать файл.

Comment: VladD порекомендовал собственный формат создать с фиксированной длинной..уже отметили. Может все же sqlite или mongodb?

Comment: @Bulson, sqlite уже стоит, как рез ее и хотел убрать, с целю сэкономить, но видимо оставлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обе сериализации — что бинарная, что XML-сериализация — являются строго потоковыми. В них невозможно чисто, без проблем найти одну нужную запись и обновить. Подумайте, что будет, если новая запись короче или длиннее старой?

Если вы хотите обновление конкретных записей, вам стоит придумать собственный формат. Например, такой, в котором записи имеют фиксированную длину в байтах (если это возможно).

Другой вариант, подсказанный в комментариях — база данных. Впрочем, обновление в базе данных одной записи может оказаться и медленнее, чем полная перезапись файла при бинарной сериализации, так что имеет смысл попробовать оба варианта для конкретно ваших данных и сравнить.